# Laravel: Display query with 10 random rows from mysql with paginate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I want to get from database 10 random rows and then display it on paginate.
One page should display only 1 `row` and next button should display next `row` etc.
Also i have column that contains category id so for the first page i want to display row with `cat_id = 1` for third page i want to display row that have `cat_id = 3`.
Please tell me is it possible? I have no idea how to do it.

For now i have controller:

```
$rows=Row::all()->random(10)->paginate(1);
```

And it says that there is no `paginate` method :(

Comment: use just `$rows=Row::all()->paginate(1);` and tell me what is showing in error message now?

Comment: error is same :( it's wierd couse i use paginate another place and it works:

$clients = Client::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
      ->orWhere('nip','like','%'.$search.'%')
         ->orderBy('id')
         ->paginate(20);

Comment: So try with `$rows=Row::where('id', '>=' ,1)->paginate(1);` and let me know.

Comment: Yes! Now paginate works but how can i now get random query for 10 results?

Comment: try $rows=Row::paginate(10)->random(5);

Comment: It gives only 5 results without paginate.

Answer (score 0):

The `all()` method returns a Collection while `paginate` extends a Query Builder. So if you did not need any random results, you could call paginate directly like this

```
$rows=Row::paginate(1);
```

Now, the problem with random is that it works on a Collection so you cannot use it directly before calling paginate, so here I'm going to use `orderByRaw('RAND()')`

For e.g. to order the rows randomly and get only the first row with the cat_id the same as the current page number, you can do something like this,

```
$rows=Row::orderByRaw('RAND()')->groupBy('cat_id')->orderBy('cat_id', 'asc')->paginate(1);
```

I'm assuming that there are no gaps in cat_id here.

To give a 'consistent' ordering across requests, you'll have to maintain some additional information (an integer seed in this case). You can perhaps pass this as an additional GET parameter or store it in the session.
After this, you can simply add that seed to the $rows query as

```
$rows=Row::orderByRaw('RAND('.$seed.')')->groupBy('cat_id')->orderBy('cat_id', 'asc')->paginate(1);
```

For storing the seed in the Session, this should suffice,

```
Session::reflash();
if(!Session::has('rand.key')) {
    $seed = Session::get('rand.key');
} else {
    $seed = rand();
    Session::flash('rand.key', $seed);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is it, thank you m8. But now every click on next or previous reset query and i want to refresh only when i refresh page.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do that. I updated the answer with a possible way you can do it though.

Comment: Yes this is it, but when i define variable $seed = srand();
It gives me exactly the same result, on "next" button get new random query :( And i want random query only when refresh page.

Comment: `srand()` generates a new seed but doesn't return a need. What you could do in your case possible is `srand(time()); $seed = rand()` when you want to refresh your seed and then save that seed as `\Session::put('rand.seed', $seed)` and refer to it with `$seed = \Session::get('rand.seed')` for future referrals till you want to refresh it.

Comment: really thanks for helping me but i have no idea how make it work...
Where should i save seed as session? Where should i restore session? How reset only when page refresh? I'm confused now :(

Comment: Sessions changed allways when i clicked Next or Previous :(
http://serwer.kucharski-webdeveloper.pl:8000/exam

Comment: Ok so now maybe it will be simple i want change session only when i get in to this view, when i exit view i want change session. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. But let me just make sure if this is what you exactly want. By saying you want it to remain the same on the same view, you mean you don't want it to change as long as the user does not exit the current view but only reloads the current page or navigates through the pagination buttons?

Comment: I want to make some thing like exam. User enter view with exam and app should randomize questions for him from database. New randomize result should be able only if user end exam or he left this view. I think best for me is to reset order when user click on button like START and then app show questions with paginate. For each session he should get new order.

Comment: A quick way you can do that using Sessions is to flash the data for the next request. So when the user enters the exam i.e. the 'seed' session isn't set, generate the seed and store it using `\Session::flash('seed', $seed);` After that, for each request reflash it using `\Session::reflash();` for each session after that. I'll update my answer with the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way using sql random function without refreshing order on paginate is use seed number.

```
$results = Row::orderByRaw('RAND(::SEED_NUMBER::)')->take(10)->get();
$rows = (new \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($results, 1));
```

**::SEED_NUMBER::** is number which you need to change whenever you want change order.

Comment: Thanks for reply, its work very nice but when i define variable $seed = srand(); It gives me exactly the same result

Comment: @kuchar you need to store seed number (eg: cache) and change when you need to change order of results. Are you sure that is showing all results? take(10) must be show only 10 results

Comment: When i changed "take(10)" in "take(5)" still showing me 10 results. I have for tests 10 rows in database)

Comment: @kuchar yeah you are right. Laravel is ignoring take command when you use paginate so we need to do manually pagination. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now it says "Undefined variable rows" on view :(